# Docusign after Signed how to get response in php?

Tags: docusignapi

in my MVC framework in codeignitor I have to working on docusign the electronic sign using api after sign document how to get response of that is if sign completed or process or cancel etc..

```
$response = $service->views->getRecipientView( 
    $returnUrl, $envelopeId, $contact_name, 
    $contact_email, $client_id, $authMethod
);
```

Comment: Please add some code that you have written so far.

Comment: Agreed we need some code. Also is this remote signing (DocuSign sends out an email asking the signer to start) or is this embedded (you make an API call to DocuSign and it returns a URL to start signing).

Comment: Embeded Signing . $response = $service->views->getRecipientView(
    $returnUrl, 
             $envelopeId, 
             $contact_name,
             $contact_email,
             $client_id,
             $authMethod);
This Function give me url and i will pass in i frame and complete the sign. after complete sign need response that sign complete or etc. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine what action the recipient took during the embedded signing flow by parsing the re-direct URL.  Once they are done signing in the iFrame or webview they will be re-directed to the URL you specified in your `$returnUrl` parameter.

For instance, if your return URL is `https://www.docusign.com/developer-center` and the user successfully signed the document the return URL would look like:

```
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center?event=signing_complete
```

Or if the recipient declined to sign then the return URL would look like:

```
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center?event=decline
```

All of this info (including code samples) is available through the QuickStart section of the DocuSign Developer Center and in the API Documentation.